# Taxonomic Latin Translation Dictionary

Tags: scientific-names

I can't remember where to find a taxonomic Latin dictionary. I have to do a creative writing assignment, and I have to come up with a myriad of homo sapiens [sapiens] successors, so I and need taxonomic Latin terms —for things like, whatever “homo cyborg” should be [or whatever].

Something like [medical dictionaries](http://stenobooks.com/en/product/3442/latin-and-introduction-to-medical-terminology-2017.html), but generalized beyond medicine.

Comment: If you want it to include words like "cyborg", are you really looking for a taxonomic dictionary, or just a modern Latin dictionary in general? I can't imagine many biologists are naming cyborgs.

Comment: @rolodexter I believe the link above answers your question. If not and taking Draconis' comment into account, feel free to edit it to explain more why it's not what you're looking for.